# Account integration errors in production

Tags: integration

What is this error?

> upsert failed on shipto insert transaction: duplicate value found: Legacy_System_Id__c duplicates value on record with id: 001C000001aktGT

And the account information fields are not updating into Salesforce.com correctly.

For this, I checked all the triggers, Classes, rules and I found nothing about the field that is not updating. I also checked in the Developer Console if there's any duplicate id, but I only got one row.

What might be the reason for this error?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to insert a record that has a legacy id already present in SF. If the field is unique that is not allowed. You may want to use upsetting instead

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be occurring, when you are trying to insert the record , there is field **"Legacy_System_Id__c"** in that object . The id **"001C000001aktGT"** is the record id for which the value of **Legacy_System_Id__c** field is already present in the system.That means if you open the record and see the field value of 
**Legacy_System_Id__c**  you can see the value which is present in the system and the value which you are trying to insert are the same.

for that reason error are given.you can insert the record after updating the record **Legacy_System_Id__c** field value.

Comment: They must be either updating or inserting a record, still, the issue will be same?

Comment: Can post your code what you have tried so far.